# setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener() is not applying padding and calling 2 times

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm calling `setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` to add padding/margin for my views.
My XML contains `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

**`setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener`** after being called **2 times** (on second time there insets of 0s).

Why Android returns insets twice and on the 2nd time there are zero insets value? And why my padding is not applying when I set it to the first value?

Code:

```
drawer.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener((v, insets) -> {
            profileButton.setPadding(
                    profileButton.getPaddingLeft(),
                    profileButton.getPaddingTop(),
                    insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom(),
                    profileButton.getPaddingBottom()
            );
            Timber.d("Inset applied: %d", insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom());
            return insets;
        });
```

Console output:

```
D/MainActivity: Inset applied: 53
D/MainActivity: Inset applied: 0
```

Comment: Facing same issue

Comment: I am facing the same issue